# How to make two Python scripts communicate over the internet?

Tags: python, sockets, communication

I'm looking for a way to make two Python scripts communicate over the internet. Something like what Socket.IO does with NodeJS, but without a browser, and in Python.

A constant connection (socket?) would be the best in my option, but if this is impossible or really difficult, using normal HTTP requests could be fine too.

Are there any frameworks to do this? If yes, which ones? Is there proper documentation? If no, how would this be achievable without a framework?

Answer (score 3):

[`sockets`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) are indeed what you're looking for.  The Python docs have [pretty good examples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example) at the bottom of the page I linked.

As for frameworks, there is [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) which might help streamline the socket construction and message handling for you.

Lastly, there is an [extremely helpful guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) I reference often when programming with sockets.  Warning: The guide is written for C, but the concepts apply nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to do this with `xmlrpclib` : http://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html.

It handle HTTP request.